# Apache Thrift compilation error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, build, build-process, thrift

I am trying to build apache thrift from source. After executing `./configure` (which doesn't give any errors). However, when I execute `make` I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -Wall -g -O2 -L/usr/lib  -o Benchmark Benchmark.o libtestgencpp.la -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lpthread 
libtool: link: cannot find the library `RPC/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp/libthrift.la' or unhandled argument `RPC/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp/libthrift.la'
make[4]: *** [Benchmark] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Documents/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp/test'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Documents/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Documents/thrift-0.9.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Documents/thrift-0.9.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs and how do I fix it?

Comment: What environment are you on?

Comment: But you did `./configure && make && sudo make install` the libs, did you? http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/

Comment: Yup. I did that. I am having problem during `make`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Those who can read are blessed ;-) All dependencies in place? http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/ubuntu/

Comment: I couldn't get to exeucute `sudo apt-get -t lenny-backports install automake libboost-test-dev` but its for Debian Lenny so  guess that's not a problem.

Comment: Checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643642/libtool-error-building-thrift-0-9-1-on-ubuntu-13-04?rq=1?

Comment: `sudo updatedb` and `locate libthrift.la` to see if the file is being put in the wrong directory?  (You can also do this with `find / -name libthrift.la 2>/dev/null` if you don't have root access.

Comment: Yup. They removed `cpp` support but I need to work with cpp. Also I am doing `make` on the source downloaded from GitHub

Comment: @Mark0978 - I am not able to `locate libthrift.la` after `./configure`

Comment: Then for sure check the comment by @JensG

Comment: Yup. `cd thrift-0.9.1/test/cpp/.libs
for i in ../*.o; do echo $i; ln -s $i .; done`

That helped (but I had to delete my previous files first, I had tried that yesterday after `./configure` and `make` but it didn't work. So had to delete all the old files and extract again and then do `./configure && sudo make && sudo make install`). If you could just write it as answer I would accept it (so that the question doesn't remain in the "open" queue).

Comment: I could do that, but (1) I didn't really do much and (2) IMHO we should close this as a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved this?  I am currently successfully building the tarball of 0.93 on Ubuntu trusty (14.04) on x86 and arm architectures.

I would suggest trying the 0.93 tarball, and using cmake instead of ./configure (as that's worked better for me).  Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I can answer.  This doesn't really make sense to me, but there we are.

Comment: Oh yeah. I feel your pain. Stack Overflow's behaviour for people with low rep is so frustrating.